# Python Turtle: change pencolor of square when clicking

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm still a newbie to the programming world, trying to find some help. I don't understand most of the codes. I've tried different approaches to it before I ended up here:

```
import turtle
import random

window = turtle.Screen()
#window.colormode(255)

square = turtle.Turtle()
square.speed(0)
square.hideturtle()

square.up()
square.goto(-200, 200)
square.down()

for i in range(4):
    square.forward(50)
    square.right(90)

square.up()
square.goto(-205, 205)
square.write("Change Color")


pencil = turtle.Turtle()
pencil.shape("circle")

def drawing_controls(x, y):
    if (-200 <= x <= -150) and (150 <= y <= 200):
        pencil.color(random.random(), random.random(), random.random())

#def sqc (self, x, y):


window.onclick(drawing_controls)
#window.onclick(square.pencolor(random.random(), random.random(), 
random.random()))

pencil.onrelease(pencil.goto)
```

The lines with the # comments are from one of my many previous attempts in solving this frustrating problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of your actual goal but I think the rework below will give you the behaviors you're looking for.  Rather than draw a square to click in, the turtle becomes the square that will be clicked:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import random

def drawing_controls(x, y):
    pencil.color(random(), random(), random())
    square.color(*pencil.color())

def drag_pencil(x, y):
    pencil.ondrag(None)
    pencil.goto(x, y)
    pencil.ondrag(drag_pencil)

square = Turtle('square', visible=False)
square.speed('fastest')
square.hideturtle()
square.up()

square.goto(-200, 230)
square.write('Change Color', align='center')

square.goto(-200, 200)
square.shapesize(50 / 20)
square.showturtle()

pencil = Turtle('circle')

square.onclick(drawing_controls)

pencil.ondrag(drag_pencil)

window = Screen()
window.mainloop()
```

Instead of `onrelease()`, I switched to `ondrag()` to make it more interactive.  However, using `pencil.goto` won't work smoothly, despite being a common example of an `ondrag()` handler, so I wrote a hander that disables the drag event while in the drag handler to smooth the motion.

Comment: that is definitely what i was looking for, i changed the the square into a square that will be clicked instead of drawing it with a turtle! But i still couldnt solve the coloring part. THANKS A LOT SERIOUSLY!!